# Связь двух сущностей Hibernate через строковое поле

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

Есть 2 сущности: страна(имя, код) и город(имя, код, код страны). Как hibernate объяснить что поле 'код страны' в сущности 'город' это внешний ключ на 'код' в сущность 'странa'. Все поля строковые. Заполняются через JSON.

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class City {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String code;
    @JsonAlias("country_code")
    private String countryCode;
```

```
@Entity
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Country {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String code;
    private String name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Создать поле в классе `Country`:

```
@OneToMany
List<City> cities;
```

В классе `City`:

```
@ManyToOne
Country country;
```

При этом есть аннотация `@JoinColumn`, которая добавит `id` страны для каждой строки `City`.

Но у вас не указан маппинг к таблице, то есть для какого поля нужно добавить `@Column`

Answer (score 0):

В чистом виде как вы хотите сделать не получится, всё-таки мы работаем с объектами.

Для cвязи не по первичному ключу:

```
@Entity
public class Country implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NaturalId
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String code;
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "country", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<City> cities = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
public class City {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;
    @NaturalId
    @Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String code;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "country_code",
            referencedColumnName = "code"
    )
    private Country country;
}
```

Для JSON можно добавить:

```
@JsonUnwrapped
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "id", "name", "cities" })
private Country country;
```